Is it possible to utilize a lambda function in an python-attrs converter?
I am attempting to automatically create converter functions that require metadata to operate. I am seeing odd behavior when a lambda function is used for the converter.
import attrs

def add(x, y=10):
    return x + y

def func(cls, fields):
    results = []
    for f in fields:
        y = f.metadata.get('add', None)
        converter = lambda x: add(x, y) if (y is not None) else add(x)
        print('Name:', f.name, y, converter(0))
        results.append(f.evolve(converter=converter))
    return results

Then I create a class with two fields, one with the metadata and the other without. However, the metadata does not get picked up. The print statement shows the behavior I would expect.
Data1 = attrs.make_class('Data1', 
                         {'a': attrs.field(default=1, metadata={'add': 5}), 
                          'b': attrs.field(default=1)}, 
                          field_transformer=func)
d1= Data1()
d1

# Name: a 5 5
# Name: b None 10
# Data1(a=11, b=11)

If you reverse the use of the metadata, it gets used for both.
Data2 = attrs.make_class('Data2', 
                         {'b': attrs.field(default=1), 
                          'a': attrs.field(default=1, metadata={'add': 5})},
                         field_transformer=func)
d2 = Data2()
d2

# Name: b None 10
# Name: a 5 5
# Data2(b=6, a=6)

Can someone please help me understand what is happening? Thank you!

Learn something new everyday, functools.partial did the trick.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12423614/local-variables-in-nested-functions
